# Adding "More Info" Button To Product Category/Listing Pages

Tags: magento-community, category-attribute

I would like to show "More Info" button (as opposed to add to cart) for some of my products. How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you need to modify **list.phtml**

Verify if it is present in your theme, if not copy it from:

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product

to

> /app/design/frontend/default/ACTIVE_THEME/template/catalog/product

Modify the following lines:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                <?php else: ?>
```

Replace with:

```
<p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('More Info') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('More Info') ?></span></span></button>
```

Flush the cache and refresh the page.

Always make a backup of your current themes file in case you need to revert back.